# Don't be overly friendly

Tags: sentence-usage

Suppose you have a friend, named “Sam”. You know each other for example for 3-4 months. You see sometimes he plays some offensive practical jokes or makes some impolite advances to his friends and you do not like it at all. Even it seems too offensive for you. Anyway he has not played such jokes with you yet, (you just came across his jokes with some other people in the past.) Once when you are with a company of your common friends, he starts to play some unpleasant jokes with you in front of your friends. He says some offensive words (he thinks that these all are OK and kind of jokes and you can take these jokes. So everything sounds OK and fun for him up to now.) You “severely” dislike his behaviors. You are getting a little bit annoyed and perhaps angry. (But yet you are controlling yourself.) He sees you are getting upset and as another bizarre practical joke, with a loud laughter, he smacks on the back of your neck. I think saying "***Sam, please don’t be overly friendly***" sounds quite natural under these circumstances. Am I right?
Any other suggestion will be welcome. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over(ly) friendly means the person becomes inappropriate while seeming to be friendly; from being too pushy to even touching inappropriately, so in your case I'd say it can be used with an ironic tone, implying that he's taking advantage of your friendship, or he's doing something inappropriate (abusing you verbally) in the name of friendship.I would just tell him that his rudeness or his so-called friendly behaviour has gone too far!

Comment: So you believe that it can be used with an ironic tone. Am I right? :)

Comment: Yes, it can be used with an ironic tone.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could say:

> Sam, why don't you take me seriously?

In effect you are saying "Don't joke with me."

It kind of depends on your relationship, but I don't think how he is acting is related to friendliness. He might be showing off for his friends or have some other problem he can't deal with.